# C# Batch deserialization of a lot of json files

Tags: c#, json, batch-processing, jsonconvert

I have 200.000 json files on file system.

Deserializing them one-by-one and putting them in a List takes about 4 minutes.

I am looking for fastest way to deserialize them or a way to deserialize them all at once.

**Code Sample**

The code i am using is somthing like this:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Data","*.json");
        var list = new List<ParsedData>();
        var dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            using (StreamReader filestr = File.OpenText(file))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                var  data= (ParsedData)serializer.Deserialize(filestr, typeof(ParsedData));
                list.Add(data);
            }
        }
        var dt2 = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine((dt2 - dt1).TotalMilliseconds);
```

**JSON format**

And the json sample is:

```
{

  "channel_name": "@channel",
  "message": "",
  "text": "",
  "date": "2015/10/09 12:22:48",
  "views": "83810",
  "forwards": "0",
  "raw_text": "",
  "keywords_marked": "",
  "id": 973,
  "media": "1.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out, that your Q was posted 2 minutes ago, so if you don't get an answer in 2 minutes.. It might have been faster to just proceed with what you've got! What have you got, by the way? (post your code and your json); maybe we can point out some obvious improvements (or send you to codereview so they can)

Comment: Also, tell us what you do with them after you deser'd them

Comment: depending on what your bottleneck is may try al little bit of multythreading. Just start a few tasks at ones which deserialize them. But would not help that much if the pure IO load is the problem. Dependent on how you open the files there also could be some possible optimizations that could speedup the process

Comment: Absolutely I want process them after loading. @
Caius Jard

Comment: Why do you want to deserialize them all at once? Do you hate RAM? If you're looking at fastest json deserializer then you probably should look at the new source generator from microsoft: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-source-generator/ . It probably won't get faster then that IF talking about deserializing to objects

Comment: Dear @Jskoss I want to process them. For example taking out the objects where "forwards" are greater than zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trying using a `Parallel.Foreach()`:

```cs
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Data", "*.json");
            var list = new ConcurrentBag<ParsedData>();
            var dt1 = DateTime.Now;
            Parallel.ForEach(files, (file) =>
            {
                var filestr = File.ReadAllText(file);
                var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ParsedData>(filestr);
                list.Add(data);
            });
            var dt2 = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine((dt2 - dt1).TotalMilliseconds);
```

EDIT:
Remove `var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Data", "*.json");` and then try directly:

```cs
            Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Data", "*.json"), (file) =>
            {
                var filestr = File.ReadAllText(file);
                var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ParsedData>(filestr);
                list.Add(data);
            });
```

But with 200000 files 50sec seems pretty descent.

If you use .NET6, you may use:

```
Parallel.ForEachAsync( ... async(file) => {
  var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
  var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ParsedData>(fs);
  list.Add(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hazrelle. I tries it with MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20. In this way the time decreases to 50 seconds. This is good but I'm still looking for some faster solution.

Comment: I've added some options if you want to try.

Comment: Your answer inspired me and I think I found the fastest solution. Now it takes only 5sec to complete. Please update your answer as I say. I created a ConcurrentBag of string. Then I added the JSON content of the file to the ConcurrentBag. only the JSON. Then after the loop, I joined the ConcurrentBag with "," then appended "]" and prepended "[" to the string. After that I de-serialized whole the JSON string as a list of objects

Comment: I mean instead of de-serializing each JSON file, I managed to parse them all at once

Comment: Nice you found the best solution. Your comment is useful I'm not going to edit it. You can post your own answer I think if you want.

Comment: no that's fine. I hope people read these comments too if needed.

Comment: @Hossein for MaxDegreeOfParallelism you can use `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1 }` to automatically pick up the environments available cores and use all but one. Hard coding this would not be ideal if you plan to run this code on other machines with different availabilities. I learned about this from [this article](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/maximum-degree-of-parallelism-in-csharp/), you can probably find some more useful info in there also